# Use a PHPUnit_TextUI_Command child in Symfony PHPUnit testing

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit in a Symfony2 project, installed through composer.

I need to override the command line argument handler, which is located in the `PHPUnit_TextUI_Command` class from vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php

That looks easy:

- extend this class in a child class
- override the method `handleArguments(array $argv)`
- use the child class instead of the original one in PHPUnit launcher

The problem lies in the last point. I cannot get PHPUnit to use another class than the original one when the CLI is launched, because it's hardcoded in the phpunit binary, which is installed by composer.

My two clues are:

- get the autoloader to use my child class instead of the original one, but that looks impossible because of name conflicts
- get composer to install another PHPUnit binary of my own

I'm stuck either way, any help would be very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `bin` folder where you can find a symlink to a files named `phpunit` where, in the last line, do:

```
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

In the same way, you can make a script that do the same, as example, make a file named `bin\myphpunit` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php


require './vendor/autoload.php';

MY_CUSTOMER_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

and launch as

```
bin/myphpunit
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Matteo. The file that actually calls `PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()` is not in the "bin" folder but in the "vendor/phpunit/phpunit" folder. It's then managed by composer and i cannot edit it safely. I could use your solution to run a copy of the  "vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" file but then i'd loose all future updates to that file. I'm more looking for a clean overriding at the loader or object level.

Comment: [answer to edited version] @Matteo i have no such symlink (i'm under Windows). For your second option, i still think it is dangerous to skip completely a process that is subject to change by the vendor author